# Add Image Column to a GridView After Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This is May Sample Code in ASP.NET How Can I Add A similar Image Column To All Rows After Binding

```
        gridview1.DataSource = MB.GetTest();
        gridview1.DataBind();
```

And My ASPX Page:

```
<asp:GridView  ID="gridview1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
```

I really need irt, thanks.

**Update**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:ImageField>
                </asp:ImageField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I see no Image columns ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta I don't any I need new one How Add it?

Comment: Similar to what? Please clarify your question and add relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi i would like to explain you a little there is a property called `AutoGenerateColumns="false"`  you need to set this as false

and generate columns in your aspx and bind them [Refer this Site](http://www.vkinfotek.com/gridview/gridview-autogeneratecolumns-property.html)

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Runat="server" 
  DataSource='<%# GetData() %>' AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
  BorderWidth="1px" BackColor="White" CellPadding="3" BorderStyle="None" 
  BorderColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Names="Arial">
    <FooterStyle ForeColor="#000066" BackColor="White"></FooterStyle>
    <PagerStyle ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" 
      BackColor="White"></PagerStyle>
    <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" 
      BackColor="#006699"></HeaderStyle>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Picutre ID" DataField="PictureID">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" 
              VerticalAlign="Middle"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Title" DataField="Title"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date Added" DataField="DateAdded" 
          DataFormatString="{0:d}">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="PictureURL"></asp:ImageField>
    </Columns>
    <SelectedRowStyle ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" 
       BackColor="#669999"></SelectedRowStyle>
    <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066"></RowStyle>
</asp:GridView>
```

There you go with Image column above

**`<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="PictureURL"></asp:ImageField>`**

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479350.aspx) is another best site to refer...
above code is taken from MSDN website.